# в JSFiddle не отображается картинка

Tags: html, html5, изображения, jsfiddle

в JSFiddle не отображается картинка, вставленная в качестве ссылки HTML5 в html блоке. В чем проблема? По моему необходим какой то тег в css блоке.

```
<h4 class="produkt">Подробнее о товаре</h4>
<div class="think">
    <div>
        <img src="../img/lenovo-thinkpad-t560.png" alt="lenovo-thinkpad-t560" title="T560" width="200" height="150">
```

Comment: покажите код, догадаться без кода почему она не отображается - невозможно

Answer (score 1):

У вас указан относительный адрес `../img/lenovo-thinkpad-t560.png` - картинки в каталоге очевидно нет. Такой адрес будет работать локально, либо на вашем сайте. Подробно об адресах можете почитать [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/znacheniya-atributov-tegov/adres).

Вам нужно указать абсолютный адрес, он должен выглядеть наподобие: `http://site.ru/img/lenovo-thinkpad-t560.png`

Чтобы получить такой адрес, сначала нужно загрузить свое изображение на сервер в сеть, и затем у загруженного изображения скопировать адрес и вставить на место старого адреса

Comment: В случае введения абсолютного ситуация та же..<img src="https://yandex.ru/images/search?img_url=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2Fb%2Fb8%2FLenovo_logo_2015.svg%2F500px-Lenovo_logo_2015.svg.png&p=1&text=logo&noreask=1&pos=59&rpt=simage&lr=2" alt="#">

Comment: вам нужен полный адрес конкретного изображения например - "https://ds-kart.ru/wp-content/uploads/Panasonic_logo_logotype_blue-1440x221.png"

Comment: и все же без полного кода догадаться невозможно, что у вас там именно происходит